# Не рендерятся изменения в шаблонах

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Друзья, добрый день.

Есть Django-проект, задеплоенный на VPS (nginx, gunicorn).

Вношу изменения в шаблоны, перезапускаю nginx и gunicorn, но изменения почему-то всё равно не рендерятся.

Не подскажете, в каком направлении копать? Заранее спасибо.